# Ubuntu package:libcaca security vulnerability (CVE-2021-30498, CVE-2021-30499)

Tags: 20.04, package-management, upgrade, security, vulnerability

I'm using `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (focal)` with `XFCE DE`, on a `AMD 64-bit` machine. When I did `apt` upgrade today, the `package: libcaca0` was upgraded as below:

`Unpacking **libcaca0:amd64 (0.99.beta19-2.1ubuntu1.20.04.2)** over **(0.99.beta19-2.1ubuntu1.20.04.1)**`

I just googled out of curiosity to see what this package does & encountered this page: https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5119-1

It says that there is a known security vulnerability in this package & need to be upgraded to: `libcaca0 - 0.99.beta19-2.2ubuntu2.1`, in order to mitigate it. However, as you can see, `apt` only upgrades to the version `19-2.1`.

I tried to upgrade the particular package only, using

`sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install libcaca0`

but, it says `libcaca0 is already the newest version (0.99.beta19-2.1ubuntu1.20.04.2).`.

This page says that there's no fix available till 2021-10-13:
https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-30499

However, as per this page, `ver: 19.2.2` has been released on 2021-03-20.
https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/libcaca/0.99.beta19-2.2

And, the download seems to be available at:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libcaca/0.99.beta19-2.2ubuntu1.1

*(I noticed that the release confirmation page belongs to Debian, while the download page points to Ubuntu. I believe, both the release & download pages **will** be available for both distros. So, the question is not about that.)*

## My question

If the package version is available for download (for Ubuntu)? Why `apt` couldn't upgrade to it? Is it because of some approval pending? If so, why there's a download available?

My intention is not to complain, but rather to scrutinize/understand the generic process/reason & what to do in this/these kind of situations - like:

- whether to download the available tar & install, or to wait for `apt` version to be available,
- shouldn't the users be notified of such issues (esp. on security vulnerabilities), or is it not possible at all,
- if the package has a vulnerability, why even the apt upgrade recommends it (and, is it not possible to remove it until a fix is available - of course, provided an alternative package is available to meet other dependencies)
- etc.

And, if possible, some expert notes on the technicalities of the  vulnerability, how/why it is caused, etc [I know.. I should look it up myself.. but, still! :) ].  Even though I'm using it for quite sometime now, I'm relatively new to Linux & not yet even a core user - leave alone a contributor.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't read your link carefully.

https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5119-1

> Ubuntu 20.04

```
caca-utils - 0.99.beta19-2.1ubuntu1.20.04.2
libcaca0 - 0.99.beta19-2.1ubuntu1.20.04.2
```

So you got the correct update. You have the fix installed already. No action is required.

`libcaca0 - 0.99.beta19-2.2ubuntu2.1` is for Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed it.. but, what do you mean by 'rot'? So, should I delete the question or something? By the way, the vulnerability still applies to 20.04 too, right? If so, my other questions remain relevant, isn't it?

Comment: It was a typo. I meant "got".

Comment: The vulnerability has been fixed for 20.02 and you already have it fixed. So what is the problem?

Comment: "Why download is available" isn't an issue. Do you need any more explanation?

Comment: No.. unless, you have some more detailed information on what this vulnerability is about. Also, I still have the question, as a user, I was still using the package till this time & I had no idea that there is such a vulnerability (whether I'd have done something about it, is a question, but still). And, while reading about this, I came across some other vulnerabilities too. I'm just wondering if there's a way to keep informed on such stuff. Anyway, I'm going to delete this question, as it is misleading/mis-informing. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't delete the question. It is not a bad one. I have no information on this specific issue. But there are a lot of places where you can track vulnerabilities. But they are fixed fast enough. So keeping your system updated is enough in most of the cases.